# Making a Bar Chart in R with filter

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, filter

I'm still new to R and Stackoverflow and was looking for help. My assignment is about the World Cup. I want to make a bar chart that shows the abbreviations of country names on the x-axis and the attendance of their stadiums on the y-axis. I used the code below and got a graph that I attached as an image to see what I made. The problem is that the x-axis shows all the countries in the dataframe and I only want about 10 selected countries. Is there anything I'm missing and what can I do. Thank you

CODE:

```
   WorldCupMatches %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = Home.Team.Initials, y = Attendance)) +
 geom_col()
```

[image: My graph]

Answer (score 0):

OP, you can filter the dataset before you pipe into `ggplot(...)`.  There are a few ways to do this, but I find using `dplyr::filter()` function to be one of the simplest.  You can specify to only include rows in your dataframe that satisfy a particular condition:

```
WorldCupMatches %>% 
dplyr::filter(Home.Team.Initials %in% c(...) ) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = Home.Team.Initials, y = Attendance)) +
 geom_col()
```

Just specify `c(...)` to be a vector of the home team initials you want to see shown in the plot.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately when I did that the chart went blank lol, did I do something wrong. I ran a is.vector check and my nations list was a vector. is there anything that you can obviously tell I did wrong?